# Why is this compiling on Visual Studio when it doesn't compile on GCC or Clang?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

In the definition of the function below the class definition, the second two "typename"s shouldn't be there according to GCC and Clang, but it compiles on Visual Studio. Anybody know why? Compiling my code on different compilers is pretty hard when Visual Studio doesn't seem to conform to the spec in a lot of ways.

```
#include <iostream>

class BaseClass { };

/* CLASS DEFINITION */
template <typename getter_t, typename setter_t>
class MyClass : public BaseClass
{
public:

    using getter_return_t = int;
    void reset_value_to(const getter_return_t&, const char* to_append);
};


/* FUNCTION DEFINITION */
template <typename getter_t, typename setter_t>
void MyClass<typename getter_t, typename setter_t>::reset_value_to(const getter_return_t& value, const char* to_append)
{
    std::cout << "Yo";
}


int main()
{
    MyClass<int, int> c;
    c.reset_value_to(5, nullptr);
}
```

Clearly it's wrong, but it compiles on Visual Studio on C++20, and I've disabled language extensions. Are there other options I can set to make Visual Studio compiler more conformant?

Comment: "Clearly it's wrong" - it's not so clear to me.  `typename` shouldn't hurt, and it's necessary in some contexts.  What errors do GCC and Clang show?

Comment: MSVC isn't exactly known for being conformant, can't say I'm surprised.

Comment: _Are there other options I can set to make Visual Studio compiler more conformant?_ - There is also [/permissive-](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-170) but it is the default for C++20 and often bugged implementation is just a bug. In this particular case it does not look a big deal - correct code is compiled as well, it could be worse.

Comment: I would treat this as a "helpful" extension from MSVS.

Comment: Why do you have both `getter_t` and `getter_return_t`? What's the purpose of that?

Comment: @Ben It's just an example. What's really interesting is that the compiler recognises getter_return_t as a function argument type, I didn't expect that.

Comment: @MarkRansom `typename` in a type specifier must be followed by a qualified name, i.e. at least one `::` must be there. Which is exactly what clang says. gcc gets totally confused by this syntax and doesn't recognize that there are two template parameters to `MyClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the output from the compiler explorer, it seems the problem is here:

```
template <typename getter_t, typename setter_t>
void MyClass<typename getter_t, typename setter_t>::reset_value_to(const getter_return_t& value, const char* to_append)
```

MSVC accepts that, but Clang does not.

It should probably just be this, without the extra `typename` keywords:

```
template <typename getter_t, typename setter_t>
void MyClass<getter_t, setter_t>::reset_value_to(const getter_return_t& value, const char* to_append)
```

MSVC, GCC, and Clang accept that.

Comment: And MSVC is wrong to accept the original code without a diagnostic: A _typename-specifier_ (i.e. a _type-id_ introduced by `typename`) must always contain a nested name specifier, not just a single identifier. (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.res.general#nt:typename-specifier)